# What advantage is gained by placing a literal value on the LHS of a boolean expression?

Tags: optimization, coding-style

I've noticed a subtle trend among some developers who consistently place the literal value of a boolean equality expression on the left hand side of the expression.

**Example:**

```
//Style #1, the style in question
if (null == object.Value || 0 == object.Value) doSomething();

//Style #2, the way I've always written it
if (object.Value == null || object.Value == 0) doSomething();
```

Is there any measurable advantage gained by writing the boolean expressions like #1? I can't see why it would evaluate any faster at runtime, but I wonder if perhaps some compilers can optimize #1 more readily than #2? If so, please explain which compilers and why.

I've always considered this simply a matter of personal taste (perhaps there is a readability argument to be made), but I've seen enough code written like #1 that I wonder if there is more to it than I'm aware of.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2430307/922184

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some developers follow and advocate (1) so that if they accidentally mis-type the comparison (`==`) as assignment (`=`), then the compiler will issue an error during compilation. In (2) the same mis-typing will not issue any compilation error, but it will result in flawed program logic because the `if` will always resolve to `true` due to the assignment.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've never considered this case, but it certainly makes sense to force compile-time error rather having to deal with a runtime logic bug that could be hard to spot while debugging.

Comment: Some compilers will warn about the "typo" nowadays. I just tried in MSVC and got "warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression". Not sure about GCC but I think I remember it doing something similar.

Comment: If you're using a statically typed language, you should be running a static analyzer anyhow. And at least THAT will certainly warn you about that. Small note: This style is usually called `yoda programming`.

Answer (score 1):

It often comes from a bad experience where if(A = "lit) got into a code base and was either ignored in warnings or the complier didn't have that as a warning.  Its impossible to do fall into this trap if the RHS is not an lvalue.